# algorithm complexity of a sqrt series

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

In the following algorithm:

```
for i=1 to n
    for j=1 to sqrt(i)
        //some code here
```

which would be its complexity?

For what I have gotten is the following series of the value of j:
1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3....

so when i goes from 1 to 3, j will only execute 1 time
when i goes from 4 to 8, j will execute only 2 times

At the end I got the following summation:

```
pow(1,0.5)+pow(2,0.5)+pow(3,0.5)...
```

So I suppose that is approximately less than O(n^2)

would that be right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your summation is correct, but the problem is easier than that:

The running time is in **O(n^1.5)**, i.e., **O(n*sqrt(n))**, and you know this because the code in the inner loop runs *less than* **n*sqrt(n)** times.

Furthermore, you know the bound is tight because the code in the inner loop runs *more than* **n/2*sqrt(n/2)** times as `i` goes from `n/2` to `n`, and **n/2*sqrt(n/2)** = **n*sqrt(n)/(2*sqrt(2))**.

Comment: `O(n*sqrt(n))` is not exactly right, since the inner loop runs till `sqrt(i)` and not `sqrt(n)`

Comment: It's exactly right.  **sqrt(i) <= sqrt(n)**, so it runs less than **n * sqrt(n)** times as I said.  When i >=n/2 , then **sqrt(i) >=sqrt(n/2)**, so it runs more than **n*sqrt(n)/(2*sqrt(2))** times.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Oswald is saying that your upper bound might be tighter than what your answer actually says.  And you should avoid used words like `exactly`, since on SO there is usually more than one way to do something.

Comment: FWIW, I consider this answer to be correct and do not understand the distinction Oswald and Tim are trying to make, if any. Your bound is tight. What's more, the explanation you give is more direct and intuitive than my mine, which shows the same thing. Keep up the good work. Answers can be exact sometimes.

Comment: I checked the sequence manually, and it _does_ appear to be upper bounded by `O(n*sqrt(n))`, however, most terms would perform better than this.

Answer (score 1):

What you say in the question appears to be on the right track. The number of executions of the inner loop is f(n) = sqrt(1) + sqrt(2) + ... + sqrt(n). We can show this is Theta(n sqrt(n)). First, it is clear that f is O(n sqrt(n)) by choosing c = 1. For the other direction, note that sqrt(a) + sqrt(b) > sqrt(a + b) for positive a, b; then, pair off elements of the summation sqrt(1) + sqrt(n) > sqrt(1 + n), sqrt(2) + sqrt(n - 1) > sqrt(n + 1), and so on; so the summation is greater than (n/2)sqrt(n+1) when n is even. The choice c = 2 or thereabouts should therefore work for this direction: twice your summation, or thereabouts for odd n, should always be greater than n sqrt(n).